# How does django handle getting data from the database?

Tags: php, django, model, implementation

I'm trying to reproduce something similiar to Djangos' *Model* class in PHP. I was wondering how django handles the loading and saving entries from a models' table.

For example, when calling `Person.objects.all()` (`Person` being a subclass of `django.db.models.Model` of course), I expect Django to perform an SQL Query, `SELECT * FROM myapp_person`, for instance, and then transforms the data recieved from the query to instances of the Model-class. Is this correct? Then,

1. Couldn't that lead to memory overflow when there are too many entries, or is there a way Django handles this side-effect?
2. When calling `Person.objects.filter(name="Paul")`  I expect Django to perform an SQL Query like `SELECT * FROM myapp_person WHERE name = 'Paul'`, but what if `Person.objects.all()` was called before? Does django cache them or does it just perform the request for each call?

Comment: Are you trying to understand Django's ORM, or do you want to replicate it in PHP? If this is the latter, have you looked at PHP ORMs such as Doctrine?

Comment: There are some good insights here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/. Btw I think FLOW3 has also an ORM.

Comment: Not sure about all of the memory management behind the scenes, but as to your second question, Django only makes a call to the database when the objects are used, like in a loop. You can enter `p = Person.objects.all()` then `p.filter(name="Paul")` and as of yet, Django has not hit the database. Once you use the QuerySet, `for p1 in p: ...` it finally hits the database and gets records to populate the QuerySet object.

Comment: My 2cents - Redbeanphp.  It is incredibly flexible and has a tiny footprint.  The entire code base is 1 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Django reads objects from database in portions, but makes a cache inside a QuerySet object. So if you have read whole data from queryset, memory will be used.
2. All QuerySet methods which return QuerySets actually make a copy of it inside, and do not copy any cache in new object. So you can be sure that queryset always contains actual data, no matter if any of its "parents" or qs itself has been processed or not.